# TRadioButton modal input box for Android with C++Builder

Tags: android, c++builder

I'm working on an application for Android using C++ Builder 10.4 and looking for a way to show an input message to the user that let him select one of a few programmatically defined radio button alternatives, similar than the TDialogServiceAsync.InputQuery. But I can't figure out how to do that.

The idea is have a little modal result box that returns the user selection, using a  set of TRadioButtons working as a modal result square above the active window, not as part of a window together with other components made at design time nor also as an entire screen window just for this radio button kind dialog.

Does someone knows and could share some C++ Builder code, function or method to do this?

Just to be contributive, because I suspect that this is not the correct way to reach my objective, this is the code that I tested using [TDialogServiceAsync.InputQuery](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FMX.DialogService.Async.TDialogServiceAsync.InputQuery) but I don't know how (or if it is possible) to overload it changing the edit boxes by radio buttons:

```
if(ApePat[1] == ApePat[2])
    ApePat[0] = ApePat[1];
else if(ApePat[1] != "" && ApePat[2] == "")
    ApePat[0] = ApePat[1];
else if(ApePat[1] == "" && ApePat[2] != "")
    ApePat[0] = ApePat[2];
else // RUT[1] <> RUT[2] ==> usuario debe decidir cuál utilizar
{
    String Prompts[2] = {L"Opción 1",L"Opción 1"};
    String Valores[2] = {ApePat[1],ApePat[2]};
    TDialogService::InputQuery(L"Elija el ApePat más adecuado", EXISTINGARRAY(Prompts), EXISTINGARRAY(Valores), (TInputCloseQueryProc *)Met);
}
```

To make work this code it is necessary to add some pieces of code to .cpp and .h files as explained [here](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Dialogs.InputQuery).

Comment: FMX does not support the use of *modal* dialogs on Android. And `InputQuery()` is for text input only, you can't manipulate it to display RadioButtons. So, for what you are asking for, you will just have to create your own `TForm` dialog with whatever controls you want on it, and then display it asynchronously (via `Show()` instead of `ShowModal()`) and act on its result when it is closed.

Comment: Bad news, but there is an alternative solution, thanks Remy. May be in the future FMX could complement adding this kind of dialogs, for radio buttons, check boxes, combo boxes, graphics, etc., similarly as the InputQuery dialog.

Comment: I seriously doubt that will ever happen.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`FMX.Pickers.TCustomListPicker`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/FMX.Pickers.TCustomListPicker):

> **TCustomListPicker** provides basic functionality for the selection of a string item from a string list:
>
> - Retrieving and setting values for the strings in a string list.
> - Retrieving and setting the maximum number of visible items in the string list at a time.
> - Retrieving and setting the index and the height of an item.
> - **Managing an event handler** that is activated when an item is selected in a picker list.

[image: Delphi ComboBox with Picker under Android]

Under Android and iOS, *this picker looks like a dialog box*, similar to the `TDialogServiceAsync` dialogs: it is asynchronous (as it has to be with android), but it stays on top, darkens the rest of the screen, and hides when you click in the darkened area.

- See [here](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Using_Pickers_to_Provide_Platform-Specific_Behavior_and_View_of_Selection_Controls) for more details.
- Note: the FireMonkey ComboBox [uses the picker as well](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Combo_Box_Components_to_Pick_Items_from_a_List_(iOS_and_Android)).

Example (C++):

```
_di_IFMXPickerService PickerService;
TCustomListPicker*    FListPicker;
if (TPlatformServices::Current->SupportsPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXPickerService))) {
    PickerService = TPlatformServices::Current->GetPlatformService(__uuidof(IFMXPickerService));
    FListPicker = PickerService->CreateListPicker();
    // set FListPicker properties (including OnValueChanged event)
    FListPicker->Show();
}
```

Example (Delphi):

```
var
  PickerService: IFMXPickerService;
  FListPicker: TCustomListPicker;
begin
  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXPickerService, PickerService) then
  begin
    FListPicker := PickerService.CreateListPicker;
    //set FListPicker properties
    FListPicker.Show;
  end;
end;
```